# how to select multiple values from two drop down and display it in text-area on the click of submit

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

i want to select multiple values from two drop down and display it in text-area on the click of a submit button. I do not know how to how to get values from two different drop down and display it in single text area and how to write function in controller to get the values drop two drop down and assign it to a single variable ,so that i can use it in text area.

Comment: post your `dropdown` and `textarea`, have you tried something?

Comment: i have tried for one drop down ..ii dnt know how to do it for more than one drop down.. and even for one drop down it is not working ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model to bind selected drop down data to the controller. These are the basics of angularjs. 
Please check this sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6V66F/83/

```
$scope.containers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Box1'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Box2'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Box3'
}];

$scope.select = function(container) {
    $scope.selectedItem = container;        
};
  $scope.submit = function() {
   alert($scope.selectedItem.name +$scope.selectedItem2.name);     
};
```

Comment: i need to select multiple values ..for example if i want to select (multiple values )box1 and box2 from 1st drop down and box2 and box3 from second drop down...and diplay it in text area..thanks for the reply